# Yii2: add field to autogenerated CRUD (automatically?)

Tags: php, yii2, crud, gii

Yii2 has a feature of [generating CRUD for table with gii](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-gii.html#generating-crud).

It creates several files: controller, model, search model and views.

What if after generating CRUD I need to add more fields to the table? I see that I need to change:

- Model's

  - phpdoc
  - `rules()`
  - `attributeLabels()`
- Search model's

  - `rules()`
  - `search()` (tweak `->andFilterWhere()` calls)
- Views:

  - `index` (grid columns)
  - `_form` (model inputs)
  - `_search` (search inputs)
  - `view` (attribute rows)

A lot of work. Is there a way to do it easier/automatically? I understand that I can just regenerate CRUD with gii, but in this case all my other tweaks would be overwritten (lost).

Maybe there exist some other CRUD solution for Yii2, that does not hardcode all fields and allows table schema changes to appear automatically in the views/models? Would be glad to know about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you dont want to overwrite file or add changes manually , you have below option:

In **Gii**, after clicking preview button you can see list of files.

[image]

If file has **changes** or **already in directory** than **diff** button displayed.
On clicking **diff** button you can see changes in file.

[image]

From this **model (window)** you can **modify file** as your need or you can copy/paste code in/from **temporary file** and manage.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This method also requires lot of manual work, especially when many methods were added to the model. Currently I am trying to create CRUD in separate folder and extend my model/controller from it. But views can not be extended...

Comment: It appears that my method still requires copying code from diffs... even if I extend my model from generated model, I need to override rules and relation methods, otherwise I get wrong (not extended) models from relation methods. Thus appears that your way is the only working one. Thanks! But in addition to what you suggest, I still use not GII generated models, but my own models, extended for generated ones (to keep autocompletion in IDE).

Comment: Works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

Simple way is regenerate model and crud after adding fields to table.
If you have modification in crud, you can generate in GUI files without saving and by copy paste move new column code.